# How to not shadow variable in inner block in Julia?

Tags: julia

The code below, finding price differences is not working. Because `previous_price` variable is shadowed.

```
prices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
diffs, previous_price = [], prices[1]
for price in prices
  diff = round(price / previous_price; digits = 2)
  push!(diffs, diff)
  previous_price = price
end
```

Possible workaround is to put it in a container, but **maybe there is a better way**?

```
prices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
diffs, previous_price = [], [prices[1]]
for price in prices
  diff = round(price / previous_price[1]; digits = 2)
  push!(diffs, diff)
  previous_price[1] = price
end
```

Comment: Is there a contextual reason `previous_price` defined as an Array?  Why not an Int, like `eltype(prices)`?

Comment: @PaSTE no, I just want to make the code work, and Array was first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Are you running this in global scope or in the body of a function?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski this specific case is in the global scope, but I would like to know the proper way to do it in both cases - global or in a function, if there's a difference :)

Comment: Your Question 2 is a different question and is likely to confuse others looking at this question, so I would recommend removing it and maybe asking a new one! However, a succinct summary is: since `prices[1]` is a `missing`, `[prices[1]]` defaults to a vector of `Missing` objects (not very useful!). You can explicitly make it an appropriately typed vector by writing instead `eltype(prices)[prices[1]]` (which will use whatever the actual type of the items contained in the `prices` vector is.) I am happy to repost this on a new answer if you choose to create a new question.

Comment: @FengyangWang thanks, I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because while [local scopes](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope-1) can rebind names of parent *local* scopes, they cannot rebind names of parent *global* scopes without an explicit `global` annotation. Instead, an assignment statement `x = <...>` will create a new local binding, which causes the error you are seeing.

Therefore, several possible solutions to your problem include:

### Make the outer scope a *local* scope

This is the solution I would recommended. In general, it is best to work in local scopes because functions, loops, etc. are in local scopes, and you may want to turn your code from a script to a library and make it a function in the future. The easiest way to create a local scope is to use `let`.

```
julia> let
         prices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
         diffs, previous_price = [], prices[1]
         for price in prices
           diff = round(price / previous_price; digits = 2)
           push!(diffs, diff)
           previous_price = price
         end
         diffs
       end
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 1.5
 0.67
 2.0
```

Note that this is easily converted into a function that takes `prices` as an argument and returns `diffs`! In general, such solutions are preferred, because they are most reusable.

### Make the local scope refer to the *global* `prices`

This is not a recommended solution, because mutating global variables is inefficient and does not compose well (i.e. if you wanted to call this routine multiple times from multiple places, perhaps in different threads, they may clash with the same global variable `previous_price`!)

```
julia> prices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 2
 4

julia> diffs, previous_price = [], prices[1]
(Any[], 1)

julia> for price in prices
         global previous_price
         diff = round(price / previous_price; digits = 2)
         push!(diffs, diff)
         previous_price = price
       end

julia> diffs
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 1.5
 0.67
 2.0
```

Note the introduction of the `global previous_price` line, which forces the inner `previous_price` binding to be the global binding.

### Use a `Ref`

This solution is also not recommended in most cases, but I am including it as it is the solution you propose, but with a more appropriate container type. A `Ref` is sort of like a pointer: it allows you to change the object it contains without rewriting the binding itself. This means that there is no longer any assignment to `previous_price` in the `for` loop, and hence it now binds to the outer `previous_price`, which in this case is global. The code is the same as your possible workaround but it is more efficient and more clear what is going on.

```
prices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
diffs, previous_price = [], Ref(prices[1])
for price in prices
  diff = round(price / previous_price[]; digits = 2)
  push!(diffs, diff)
  previous_price[] = price
end
```

Note that `Ref`s are accessed with `[]`, instead of with `[1]` as your one-element vector is.

Comment: Thanks, I agree the `let .. end` approach is the best.